# how to return json objects for list<POJO> in RestController

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I have restful webservice returning list of pojo objects which is not generating correct json format.

The following is the code which is not return json object

```
@RequestMapping("/getThisWeekPlan")
public List<ShiftPlannerView> getThisWeekPlan() {

    return getShiftPlanRepo.fetchThisWeekShiftPlan();
}
```

My POJO where setting the result from JPA with hibernate using namedquery

```
    public class ShiftPlannerView {


    public ShiftPlannerView() {
    }
    private Date shiftPlannerDate;
    private String resourceName;
    private String shiftName;

    public ShiftPlannerView(Date shiftPlannerDate, String resourceName, String shiftName) {
        super();
        this.shiftPlannerDate = shiftPlannerDate;
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.shiftName = shiftName;
    }


    public Date getShiftPlannerDate() {
        return shiftPlannerDate;
    }
    public void setShiftPlannerDate(Date shiftPlannerDate) {
        this.shiftPlannerDate = shiftPlannerDate;
    }
    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }
    public void setResourceName(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
    }
    public String getShiftName() {
        return shiftName;
    }
    public void setShiftName(String shiftName) {
        this.shiftName = shiftName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShiftPlannerView [shiftPlannerDate=" + shiftPlannerDate + ", resourceName=" + resourceName
                + ", shiftName=" + shiftName + "]";
    }


}
```

DB call

```
@Repository
```

public class GetShiftPlanRepoImpl implements GetShiftPlanRepo{

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<ShiftPlannerView> fetchThisWeekShiftPlan() {

    List<ShiftPlannerView> result= em.createNamedQuery("fetchByShiftPlannerThisWeek")
            .getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

}

The following is the response:

```
 [
    [
        "2018-04-16",
        "Elias",
        "I"
    ],
    [
        "2018-04-16",
        "Sithik",
        "II"
    ],
    [
        "2018-04-17",
        "Vikram Boya",
        "I"
    ],
    [
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: @Ossin the last part of my question is my response, I have edited it now.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire POJO including getters and setters?

Comment: Your named query probably doesn't actually return instances of ShiftPlannerView, but array of objects instead.

Comment: Most likely. Please also include the JPQL named query `fetchByShiftPlannerThisWeek`. I think you are not selecting whoe objects, but just individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

The following code changes brought me expected response

```
@Override
public List<ShiftPlannerView> fetchThisWeekShiftPlan() {

    List<ShiftPlannerView> listOfShiftPlannerView=new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        Query q= em.createNativeQuery(ShiftPlannerConstants.THISWEEKSHIFTPLANQUERY);
        List<Object[]> result=q.getResultList();
        for(Object[] row : result){
            ShiftPlannerView emp = new ShiftPlannerView();

            Date workingDays = sdf.parse(row[0].toString());
            emp.setShiftPlannerDate(workingDays);
            emp.setResourceName(row[1].toString());
            emp.setShiftName(row[2].toString());
            listOfShiftPlannerView.add(emp);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks to JB!